# Rename the Report While Exporting?

Tags: reporting

I am exporting Reports using the URL - "https://na1234.salesforce.com/00ON0000000YItU?excel=1&details=no".

**I want the report(In Printable View) downloaded, to be saved with a SPECIFIC NAME** and not with a random name like "Report124356.xls".

Is there any way out to do so....either through APEX or using a parameter in QUERY STRING.
Urgent help is required.....

Thanks in advance!!
Harshit

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link with some solution - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000093D1IAI

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer with at least a description or summary of the information ?

Comment: @Sdry, just have sfdcfox write up his solution again ;)